# DNS resolve stopped working after upgrade to 17.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, dhcp

I had a working Ubuntu 16.04 version installed. Recently, I tried to upgrade to 17.04.
After the upgrade, I couldn't browse the internet anymore. 
Ping to direct IP works, but not to a name.

Googling this, I found many references to disabling `dnsmasq`. Most point to comment out the line
`dns=dnsmasq` 
in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, but I don't even have this line there.

I tried quite many things, including clean install of Ubuntu 17.04, and have the same problem.
Seems that the local DNS isn't working.

2 options to solve the problem temporary until the next reboot:
1. edit `/etc/resolv.conf` and add my router instead of the local loopback.
2. running `sudo dhclient`, which is doing this for me.

Is there a way to permenantly cancel local DNS, and enable just the setting from the DHCP server?

In the GUI of managing network connection, the settings look correct (using "Auto" for IPv4).

thanks

Comment: Could  you add the output of  `systemctl status resolvconf.service` and `grep hosts: /etc/nsswitch.conf`

Comment: take a look here, see comment 5 for possible fix. (if doing, after editing either disconnect/reconnect to network or just log out/in. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1654918

Comment: @user.gz: `resolvconf.service - Nameserver information manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/resolvconf.service; enabled; vendor prese
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2017-04-18 20:40:32 IDT; 2min 38s ago
     Docs: man:resolvconf(8)
 Main PID: 639 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/resolvconf.service`

Comment: @doug: tried to add it, but seems that those settings do not go anywhare.

Answer (score 1):

You can statically assign your DNS servers in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. Under the interface that your using add `dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8` or whatever DNS server you prefer to use. For example:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet auto
dns-nameserver 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: but in newer distribution, it is no longer eth0, and the new name doesn't appear in the interfaces file

Comment: You can see the name of the interface in the output of `ifconfig` most likely it will be something along the lines of `enp3s0`